# Starting Glassfish without Sudo

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal, glassfish

I am currently having a problem starting Glassfish inside Eclipse on OS X. It just hangs whilst trying to start the domain.

I think the problem may lie with the permissions of Glassfish - When I use the 'start-domain domain1' command even in terminal, I must use 'sudo' otherwise I get a 'permissions denied' error. If I use 'sudo', then the server starts successfully from terminal.

I think this error may be carrying over into Eclipse - that is, the server is trying to start but is timing out because Eclipse is not starting the server with the correct permissions etc.

Is there any way to start the server via Eclipse by giving it root permissions? Or another solution, is there any way to change the Glassfish permissions so that it can be started without the 'sudo' command?

Thanks.

Comment: what port(s) is your domain configured to listen to?

Comment: Just the default I think, 9009?

Answer (score 0):

You should have installed the glassfish directory in your home folder (it's usually /home/user/ on linux - I haven't used OS X, but I think it's the same). Re-install glassfish and make sure you place it in your home path (it's the recommended path anyway). Then reconfigure eclipse with the path of the new install.

--
Hope it helps

Comment: I have it installed in my 'user' folder on Mac OS X, I can't see why that would be a problem. I.e. users/myuser/servers/glassfish3.1.1